# Django rest framework returns 201 created, but nothing is changed in the DB

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

That's it. No errors in django console, object is reported to be created, request to django rest returns json of MyModel instance with all fields (including `id`) set to `null` even though I pass some of them non-empty. And new item doesn't appear in database.

The code is as follows:

```
class MyModelSerializer(rfs.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['id', 'foo', 'bar']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return MyModel(**validated_data)

class MyModelView(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                  generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    # TBH that seems strange to me, but tutorial suggest showing

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

url(r'^api/web/my-model/$',
    MyModelView.as_view(),
    name='my-model')
```

`MyModel` is not attached, but it works OK with standard django form-based editors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the method `create()` of `MyModelSerializer`. Just calling `MyModel(**validated_data)` will not put data into database, only create an instance of `MyModel`. To save data into database you must call `instance.save()` or `MyModel.objects.create(**validated_data)`. Your serializer should look like this:

```
class MyModelSerializer(rfs.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return MyModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

In your case, I don`t see need to overwrite the `create()` method of `MyModelSerializer` (also `post()` method of `MyModelView`). `ModelSerializer`, `CreateModelMixin` and `GenericAPIView`  already do exactly what you are doing in overwriting these methods

Comment: Actually it also works w/o overriding that method at all.

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly overriden some methods in serializer. Removed those methods and it started working.